"A potentially dangerous macro has been blocked"
There's an .ACCDB that's been used for years by a bunch of people. It's been inspected for macros, it has no macros in it.

When the file is opened MS ACCESS flashes this ominous warning:


After clicking on OK, MS ACCESS flashes this even more ominous-sounding message:


When one clicks on Learn More, one is sent to this page with this panic-inducing headline:


The Question: The file has no macros in it. What can one do to get rid of these panic-inducing messages? (I want people to stop having heart-attacks just because they opened a harmless MS Access file.)

saved queries are also handlet as macros, because it could have hazardous contenet
